# Error during packaging tflite runtime with pysintaller

Tags: tensorflow, pyinstaller, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to package the tflite runtime in pyinstaller so that I can share the file with others. However everytime I run the packaged program. It gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[15468] Failed to execute script gallerycleaner
```

It works fine when it's in .py format. I even tried adding the tflite runtime in the hidden imports section but it still doesn't work

```
hiddenimports=['tflite_runtime'],
```

Please note I cannot import the whole tensorflow package because that way the file size increases drastically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we peek into the `interpreter` module from the `tflite_runtime` package, we'll find the following code.

```py
# interpreter.py
if not __file__.endswith(os.path.join('tflite_runtime', 'interpreter.py')):
  # This file is part of tensorflow package.
  from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader
  from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export as _tf_export
```

It appears that `pyinstaller` messes up the `__file__` variable during the bundling process. As a result, this code branch (which wouldn't be executed otherwise) is run, causing the `tensorflow` import attempt. You can read more about this behavior [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file).

One possible approach, though not ideal, is to replace the if statement with the following code before bundling the application.

```py
# interpreter.py
if False:
```

That way, the application won't try to import `tensorflow` and the issue should be solved.

Comment: Started getting the following error 

```
  File "c:\users\moizsohail\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 365, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\moizsohail\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\_tf_stack.pyd'
```

Comment: Nvm it got fixed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share the hook you used? @MoizSohail